# How to pass function with specific input to function which validates this input? - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using `MVC` (`Module-View-Controller`) pattern in my project. I want to keep my code DRY(Don't repeat yourself) so I don't want to write get_date function again just for another input.

I use function `get_date()` several times, but with different inputs. How can I pass these inputs to function `get_date()` so it could work?

Here I call `get_date()` function:

```
date = get_date(date_input = provide_date())
```

Here I want to pass the function with input message:

```
def get_date(date_input):
    ask = True
    while ask:
        date_input
        try:
            validation = datetime.strptime(date_input, '%Y-%m-
%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            date_list = validation.split('-')
            correct_date = 
date(int(date_list[0]),int(date_list[1]),int(date_list[2]))
            return correct_date
            ask = False
        except ValueError:
            wrong_input()
```

Provide_date function is:

```
def provide_date():
    return input('Type date in format Y-M-D: ')
```

I have another inputs for different situations like reschedule with another message.

How can I pass this input to `get_date()` function so it could work inside While loop? Cause now it loops forever when I raise TypeError.

Comment: The line that has just `date_input` does not do anything. Did you mean to pass `date_input` to the function (instead of `date_input()`) and then call `date_input()` on that line? The two are not equivalent.

Comment: @tobias_k yes, exactly. How should I do that? The input have to be called inside While loop to work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

- you *call* the function and then pass the result to `get_date`; instead, pass the function itself
- then, *call* the function within `get_date`, and also bind the result to some variable
- no need to parse the date, then format it, then parse it again, manually
- since you return from the function, no need for the `ask` variable

Try this:

```
def get_date(date_input):
    while True:
        inpt = date_input()  # add () and bind result to variable
        try:
            dt = datetime.strptime(inpt, '%Y-%m-%d')  # no need to parse-format-parse
            return date(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day)  # use attributes of parsed datetime
        except ValueError:
            wrong_input()

print(get_date(provide_date))  # no () here
```

Comment: Thank you @tobias_k for help! You are right. But the problem is, that I want to call get_date(date_input) function again, but with another input which is defined in function:

    def date_for_reschedule_event():
        return input('Enter the date of the event you want to reschedule: ')

How can I pass these functions with inputs to get_date() function, so I didn't have to write get_date() function again for another input?

Comment: @JeyKey I don't understand the question. Just pass the function (the function itself, not the result of calling the function), as I did in the answer, i.e. `get_date(date_for_reschedule_event)`

Comment: Sorry for that @tobias_k. I didn't see that you are calling that function in 3rd line of your code, that you passed. The name of that function misled me. Now everything works great ;) thank you for help!